# Component for list based suggestion of terms (autocomplete/autosuggest) in web based application

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, web, patternmatching

I search a component that is able to autocomplete / suggest / predict based on manual user input. You know this from Amazon where you get a suggested list of products based on what is on offer as soon as you start typing.
This could be done using a pure JavaScript approach but I think this will have to be backed by a server side component to achieve satisfactory performance so I search a solution that needs Javascript solely for input handling.

Top priority

- support for desktop and mobile browsers
- can be used with AngularJs
- can cope with typos (user enters 'hose', word in list is 'house')
- is able to find patterns inside a word (user enters 'marine', word in list is 'submarine')
- fast (suggestion shown in less than 300ms)
- can be free / gratis or in need of a paid license
- supports list up to 30000 entries in size
- only needs JavaScript (client) and Java (server)
- is able to import from text file (csv, xml, json) and (optional) database (through jdbc)

Optional:

- small footprint (does not need a database on the server side after initial startup, can work in memory until updated data is provided)
- can be used in native mobile apps (iOS, Android, Windows mobile)
- support for categories (the list contains the information which category a word belongs to. If two found entries are in different categories their name is returned)
- support for metadata like a preview image link (a user enters 'ouse' and a preview image of a house and a mouse is shown)

Answer (score 1):

The Syncfusion [ejAutoComplete](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/angularsupport/AutoComplete) JavaScript control can be used for displaying a list of suggestions.

It can't catch typos, but can do everything else on your required list.

support for desktop and mobile browsers: Yes
can be used with AngularJs: Yes

can cope with typos (user enters 'hose', word in list is 'house'): No

is able to find patterns inside a word (user enters 'marine', word in list is 'submarine'): Yes

fast (suggestion shown in less than 300ms): Yes

can be free / gratis or in need of a paid license: Yes

supports list up to 30000 entries in size: Yes

only needs JavaScript (client) and Java (server): Yes

is able to import from text file (csv, xml, json) and database (through jdbc): Yes

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.